# Error when running Rails with Ruby 1.9.2 under RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I try to run a Rails application when using Ruby 1.9.2 under RVM, I get the following error:

```
/Users/purinkle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [rake-0.9.2] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /Users/purinkle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
        from /Users/purinkle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1182:in `gem'
        from /Users/purinkle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
```

If I try to run the same command while using Ruby 1.8.7, everything works fine.

Why would this happen?

Comment: Do you have Rails installed? Have you ran `bundle install`?

Comment: Ruby versions do not share gems, if you newly install a ruby version, all gems, including rails, bundler need to be installed specifically for that ruby version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am a newbie, but I can say you are missing the installation of Rails related to Ruby 1.9.2.

To check :

```
rails --version
```

To try solving this, reinstall rails for Ruby 1.9.2:

```
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and it was as simple as

```
gem install rails
```

then

```
bundle update
```